# Dell PowerEdge R710 NIC Configuration

Tags: networking, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I have Dell PowerEdge R710 that is currently being used inside LAN to host some virtual machines. It is running Windows Server 2016 standard as host operating systems and all VMS are running inder Hyper-V

As it has 4 network adapters, I am thinking to expose one network adapter to WAN interface and expose it to the PfSense (or Sophos) running on my Hyper-V. and then from LAN out form other network adapter on server, I would like to take it to a smart switch and then from there, I would like to utilize two other network adapters to use LAN ports.. Here is how it looks like:

WAN --> NIC1 on PE R710 --> PFSense running in Hyper-V --> NIC2 on PE R710 --> switch --> NIC3 & NIC4 on PE R710

I don't know if this is an ideal scenario because I want to make sure that from WAN, traffic always hits the PFSense and then flows inside my LAN.

My question is, does this setup exposes my Host OS (Windows Server 2016) on 
server and all underlying VMs? I need to run Freenas and other critical VMs that I don't want to expose outside.

How can I assure that HOST OS can only be accesses within LAN and always use the NICs which are exposed to a LAN and not the WAN?

Is this really an ideal setup? I am currently running PfSense on a separate box and I want to consolidate all my boxes within this server and just run everything within.

How much would be the power consumption of PE R710 in comparison to running three Core2Duo machines. As per my research, it would be cost effective to run all three VMs on server than running on three individual machines.

Please let me know if I am not clear in my questions about this setup. I will be glad to clarify it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe give some details about what is on the other side of the WAN Ethernet cable.  Also the power consumption could be a separate question, you're probably correct that its more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is the opportunity for your other applications on the host to be exposed, but it's possible to take reasonable measures against that.  Your hardware is becoming a router, so will need to be made as secure as one.  If your WAN is provided by a router you control, maybe you don't need to make your server a router.

It looks like the main thing to do is dedicate your WAN port to Hyper-V, see this question: [How to dedicate a NIC to a VM in Hyper-V](https://serverfault.com/questions/461699/how-to-dedicate-a-nic-to-a-vm-in-hyper-v)

Do not "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter."  Then your applications won't try to use the WAN port.

Then you will need to use the firewall features in pfSense.  Block everything by default, and permit only the network traffic you need.  Whatever applications use that traffic will need to be secure and up to date.  pfSense will need to be kept up to date, if there are any vulnerabilities then they would have access to pfSense and from there the rest of your network.

The Dell BIOS and firmware for the Ethernet would also need to kept up to date, as there might be some low level vulnerability.

Comment: axus, I am currently using Verizon Fios Gateway router which is almost 5 years old as my WAN interface, From Spectrum modem, it goes to Fios Gateway router and then I feed it into my current PfSense box. So you still advice that I need to pass my WAN through Fios Gateway router before feeding it to the PE-R710 for the pfSense. If I do that, do I still need to update low level hardware drivers and keep it up-to-date? I keep my PfSense pretty up-to-date

Comment: I think I have the same router; for a residential use, Verizon is updating it automatically with patches.  So, it will be the front-line and you don't need to worry about your PowerEdge ethernet drivers so much.  The routing situation becomes more complicated, though; you'll need to define some static routes in the Fios Gateway, if the subnet behind your pfSense is different.

Comment: axus, how routing can make a difference. For e.g. my IP provided by my ISP is 172.25.25.68 and from Fios Gateway, I get 192.168.1.10 (for e.g... I probably can make it static in Fios router.. I am not so sure though) to my PfSense WAN. PFSense has one lan and vlan for IOts. with 192.168.30.1/23 and 192.168.70.1/24 ranges. What kind of routing do i need? I am sorry but I am not a networking guy.